# Stone in the middle?

Tags: nouns

When I read a Children's Illustrated Dictionary, I found an example sentence as this,

**Apricot**

An apricot is a soft round fruit. It has a big `stone` in the middle.

How to replace the `stone` with another better word in the example? *core*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**kernel** is a synonym to **stone** in that context, as is **pit**. If the stone in question is small, you could use **pip** or **seed**.

Comment: Just a note to add that *stone* is the proper word for the seed inside apricots, peaches, nectarines and similar fruit. In fact, peach varieties are divided into *clingstone* and *freestone*, depending on whether or not the flesh fibers attach to the stone.

Comment: ...and one of these days I'm going to start remembering to upvote when I make a comment that is complementary to an answer. My brain seems to think that since I've clicked *something*, I'm done with the page.

Comment: "Stone" is the only word for that in my normal vocabulary. "Kernel" and "pit" I recognise, but would not use either of them in this sense.

Comment: In middle-America I often hear the term 'pit' used for peaches, apricots, nectarines, plums, cherries, etc.  I don't think I've heard anyone in this area call them 'stones'.